# "No Certificates are available" when adding iOS provisioning profile for Parse Push Notifications

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm following [this tutorial](https://parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications) to set up push notifications for my iOS app, using Parse. When I get to part 2, which involves creating a new Provisioning Profile, I get to step 6, and see this:

[image]

When I look at my certificates however, I see that there is in fact one there:

[image]

I've tried following other stackoverflow posts that address this issue, and it doesn't seem to fix my problem, perhaps because the layout for the Appe dev website seems to have changed a bit. Why aren't I able to create a provisioning profile to set up Parse Push Notifications?

Comment: I'm having this problem, too. I've been stuck for hours. Did you ever solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The certificate you created is intended to be uploaded to the Parse website, in the settings section of your app.  You need to create a separate certificate to go with your provisioning profile.  Create a new certificate, and select either iOS App Development, or App Store certificate, depending on what stage you are at.  I'm assuming it's Development in this case.  You don't need to attach the Push certificate to your provisioning profile.